# C4355 'this' used in base member initializer list

Tags: c++, c++17, this

I'd like to know if this code is valid or has an undefined behaviour, because my MSVC gives a warning `C4355 this used in base member initializer list`.

```cpp
struct S
{
    string s_1;
    string s_2;

    S(string&& s_1, const string& s_2)
        : s_1{ std::move(s_1) },
        s_2{ s_2 + this->s_1 }
    {

    }
};
```

Is it allowed to use `this` pointer in this case? Compiled with MSVC with a flag /std:c++17.

Comment: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#15 [Note 7: The *expression-list* or *braced-init-list* of a *mem-initializer* is in the function parameter scope of the constructor and can use `this` to refer to the object being initialized. — end note]

Comment: That warning is to warn that not all members of `this` has been constructed / are available. (`s_1{this->s_2}` would be a mistake). It is fine usage here.

Comment: delegating constructor might help to get rid of the warning: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/E1zK9asxG).